# Row height in regression models with jtools in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, huxtable

I would like to adjust the row padding in a `jtools` regression table. I tried `set_row_height` since I read that the underlying structure is a `huxtable`. But I'm unsure, and it didn't work.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Name"
date: "10 5 2021"
output: html_document
---

## R Markdown

```{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
mymodel <- lm(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars)

library(tidyverse)
library(jtools)
library(huxtable)

export_summs(mymodel, scale = TRUE) %>%
  set_font_size(6) %>%  # working in markdown html
  set_row_height(., everywhere, 0.1)  # not working in html
```
````

It looks fine in RStudio, but uses extensive row space in Markdown. `set_font_size` is working, but `set_row_height` not.

[image]

Comment: Show your code for `set_row_height()`. Did you try `set_tb_padding()`?

Comment: I edited to show `set_row_height()`. Did not manage to use `set_tb_padding()` yet.

Comment: You don't need the `.`  in `set_row_height` btw.

Comment: Any luck so far?

Comment: No luck, I tried without `.`, with and without `everywhere` and different values for row height.

Comment: And have you read `?row_height`? "Numeric heights are scaled to 1 and treated as proportions of the table height in HTML"... try CSS values.

Comment: I can increase the row height with `"4em"` but cannot decrease it with `"0.4em"`. Negative values also have no effect.

Comment: Is `"0.4em"` output to HTML? My guess is yes (if not, probably a bug). If so, then blame the browser/the CSS specification. You might try fixing `height()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, row height adjustment worked with `set_tb_padding`. I cannot replicate why it didn't worked in the first place. `set_row_height` requires CSS/LaTeX values, i.e. `set_row_height("4cm")`. I cannot reduce row height to a resonable size but can increase row height.

---

````
title: "Jtools and Huxtable"
author: "Name"
date: "10 5 2021"
output: html_document
---

## R Markdown

```{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
mymodel <- lm(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars)

library(tidyverse)
library(jtools)
library(huxtable)

export_summs(mymodel, scale = TRUE) %>%
  set_font_size(10) %>% 
  set_tb_padding(1)
```
````

[image]